# What does xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax mean on Grid Layer?

Tags: qgis

I made a grid layer over a country and the data display on it is ID, xmax, xmin, ymax and ymin. It's clear that the last 4 parameters are the dimensions of the square of each ID, but what is the reference? I was expecting a latitude/longitude coord and I dont know how to work with these ones.

[image]

Comment: Do the numbers for xmax, xmin, etc. correspond to the number of grid squares in each direction? What are the units of your grid squares?

Comment: @lambertj Sorry, I forgot to upload an image. My quares are 40Km side, so the differente between xmin-xmax and ymin-ymax is correct. I have just edited it. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units shown are the project's currently selected coordinate system units.

Go to Project -> Properties -> General and investigate there. Specifically toggle "Coordinate display" to change the Coordinate display at the bottom of the map window to show coordinates in "Map units".